# how to export the multiple data in csv forat which is strong in differnt db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 different modules in each modules different data's but all the modules actions i have written in one controller, now i want
to export the data 4 different else in one sheet only .... tell me how
export in CSV format.

Employee is the main controller in that only i have written all other actions..
personal_info , employee_qualification, Employee_proof, employee_skill, relatives these are the other modules now i need to be export the data in csv format

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) gem which can convert activerecord objects to CSV with ease, including in separate sheets.